# Bigquery - loading CSV with "#N/A" in one column

Tags: google-bigquery, gsutil

How can i load a csv successfully using bq load (gsutil) where a FLOAT column has few values as #N/A.

I get the below error when i use the below bq load

```
bq --location=australia-southeast1 load --max_bad_records=20 --allow_jagged_rows --skip_leading_rows=1 --source_format=CSV  DATASET1.T1.FILE1 gs://load_files/Test/FILE!.csv
```

ERROR - Could not parse #N/A as double for field blah blah

Modifying csv file is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `--null-marker` flag (cf [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options)), specifying "#N/A" as a special null character.